# Method to estimate times of individual impulses from composite response

Tags: time-series, measurement, impulse-response

I have a detector that registers a sequence of "hits" over a period of time.  Each hit produces a signal that has the approximate form

$h(t)=Ae^{-(t-t_0)/\tau_d}\left(1-e^{-(t-t_0)/\tau_r}\right)\quad(t>t_0)$,

where $\tau_d$ and $\tau_r$ are the decay and rise times, and $t_0$ is the time of the hit. This looks as follows:

[image: sample response function]

The detector will sum the responses to each of the hits and then sample the resultant waveform to produce a final discrete-time signal.

What I would like to to is take this composite signal and estimate as best as possible the times of the individual hits.  The hits may be very closely spaced, so there is significant overlap between the signals and individual peaks may not be discernible. My question is, what is the best way to approach such a problem?  The signal is just a sequence of impulses convoluted with the response curve, so is there a way to "reverse" this convolution?  I don't have much experience with this kind of thing so any help would be appreciated.